# When do exactly an Access Point (AP) sends a Beacon Frame?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, frame

I am trying the make a script in Python with scapy that captures the Packets around in the air. When i put the Wireless Card in Monitor Mode, it is supposed to capture Beacon Frames automatically but it doesn't. But when i start airodump-ng script, scapy starts capturing Beacon Frames as normal. My question is Why this happens? Doesn't the Access Points automatically transmits Beacon Frame after specific intervals of time? Or if they do then why i'm not able to capture packets with Scapy with the same speed as of airodump.

NOTE: Sometimes, scapy works and captures Beacon frames but not as fast as airodump-ng do.

Comment: You must make sure that you are capturing on the same channel as your Access Point.  By default, most APs beacon every 100ms.  There is no way you can miss beacons unless your AP is misbehaving or you are capturing on the wrong channel.

Comment: Thanks. But it's been 5 months since I asked this question and until now i figured this out myself.

Comment: Glad to hear it.